# asmack XMPPTCPConnection ignores host

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am trying to use the asmack build of the smack library, but got stucked in the first steps. The following code shows that host is null inside the XMPPTCPConnection. I've tested versions 4.0.0 and 4.0.4 of the jars available at http://asmack.freakempire.de/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
    public static final int PORT = 5222;
    public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        SmackAndroid asmk = SmackAndroid.init(context);
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
        connConfig.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
        connConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);

        XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Connection host " + connection.getHost());
    }
}
```

The log simply shows the `I/XMPPChatDemoActivity(30917): Connection host null` line.

I am testing on a real android 4.0 device. ProGuard is disabled, as i am compiling with `ant debug` mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not ignore the `host` setting of ConnectionConfiguration. The 'host' is only initialized after you call `connect()`, since when using XMPP with DNS SRV RR the actual host used for establishing the connection will only be available after the DNS lookups are done.

Comment: Thank you @Flow. I started with a whole example for connecting to gtalk service and, as it was failing, i kept removing code to get somenthing that worked, and that snipped above is what i got in the end :s